Cookie suddenly does not work (express-session, cookie-parser)
I use cookies to save my sessionID because I don't want to allow certains users to have two sessions opened at the same time.
Sometimes, many users are logged out at the same time. I can't really see what I did wrong.
For the backend, I use:


"cookie-parser": "^1.4.6",



"express-session": "^1.17.3",



For the frond end, only:


"restful.js": "^0.9.6",



What I do, is that I have my middleware to check if the session is still live but req.cookies is not found while I can see that it's in the client side browser.
Here is my middleware:
const verifySessionID = async (req, res, next) => {
  if (req.user.unlimitedSessions) {
    return next();
  }

  if (req.cookies && req.cookies.sessionID) {
    try {
      const sessionIds = await getAllSessionIds();
      if (sessionIds.includes(req.cookies.sessionID)) {
        return next();
      }
    } catch (e) {
      log.error('Invalid session (cookie)');
      return res.status(401).send('Invalid session (cookie)');
    }
  }
  log.error('Cookies does not exist');
  return res.status(401).send('Cookies does not exist');
};

const api = restful(`${window.location.origin}/api`, fetchBackend(fetch));

This is how I use api in the front end.
I also wanted to say that it only does it in production not in local
I've tried to log into two differents account to see if then I logged into one of these accounts to check if It can have an impact.
